# how to sort span using rows and columns attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am stuck in rearrange span. Can you please help me out from this?

I have html structure like this.

```
<div class="mainUl">
<span row="0" col="0">
        00
</span>
<span row="2" col="2">        
        22
</span>
<span row="1" col="0">
        10
</span>
<span row="1" col="1">
        11
</span>
<span row="2" col="0">
        20
</span>
<span row="3" col="0">
        30
</span>
<span row="2" col="1">
        21
</span>
</div>
```

I would like to rearrange all spans in ascending order with use of jquery.

output like this.

```
<div class="mainUl">
<span row="0" col="0">
        00
</span>
<span row="1" col="0">
        10
</span>
<span row="1" col="1">
        11
</span>
<span row="2" col="0">
        20
</span>
<span row="2" col="1">
        21
</span>
<span row="2" col="2">
        22
</span>
<span row="3" col="0">
        30
</span>
</div>
```

Guys please help me out.

Comment: @Utkanos Actually i didn't know how to start?

Comment: That's invalid markup, a span can not be a child of an UL

Comment: @adeneo I update my question. now have a look. Actually my HTML is like this UL>span>li.

Comment: And what does it change? The only valid structure is `ul > li`.

Comment: you can try like this http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/V4QT2/

Comment: @raina77ow yes only arrange all span or li based on rows and columns in ascending order.

Comment: @CJRamki yes but i would like to sort based on rows and columns also. and my structure is fixed. unfortunately i can't change my structure of rows and columns attribute.

Comment: If we give you a solution there's no guarantee it will work, as you don't have the same markup that you've now posted in the question. Your UL>span>LI markup is totally invalid, and there's no way to know what the browser will do with that markup, but most likely it will move things around to try and fix the errors.

Comment: @adeneo yes but see my updated question that have only div > span markup now isn't this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow the advices you received, however this could be your starting point :

```
$('.mainUl > span').sort(function(a, b){
    var ar = a.getAttribute("row");
    var ac = a.getAttribute("col");
    var br = b.getAttribute("row");
    var bc = b.getAttribute("col");

    if (ar > br){
        return ar > br;
    };

    if (ar == br){
        if (ac > bc){
            return ac > bc;
        };
    };

}).appendTo('.mainUl');
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/4xyq9/

----- EDIT -----

The problem was not the number of elements, however here's a new version tested with more than 10 elements

```
$('.mainUl > span').sort(function(a, b){
    var ar = a.getAttribute("row");
    var ac = a.getAttribute("col");
    var br = b.getAttribute("row");
    var bc = b.getAttribute("col");

    if (ar > br){
        return 1;
    };

    if (ar < br){
        return -1;
    };

    if (ar == br){
        if (ac > bc){
            return 1;
        };

        if (ac < bc){
            return -1;
        };
    };

}).appendTo('.mainUl');
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/4xyq9/20/

Comment: Really appreciate your help but if there is more then 10 element then this will not work.